# How to change Cell refernce to other cells every 14 Days , By formula or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have data in A1 and data in B1 and **Date** in C1.

Now D1=A1 .

I need **after 14 days** from **Date** in C1, **D1 to be = B1**

**and after 14 days again** D1 to be = A1 **and so on.**

How to do that , By formula or VBA ?

[image: Sheet Image]

Comment: A more comprehensive set of sample data would be helpful. right now `B1`, `C1`, etc... are empty. Depending on what the data looks like, I would problably use either `INDEX/MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` to find a row based on the date

Comment: Data in A1 & B1 are Text only as string and C1 is Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(INT((TODAY()-C1)/14)),A1,B1)
```

or this:

```
=IF(ISODD(INT((TODAY()-C1)/14)),B1,A1)
```

Comment: I have edited my answer after you have copied it. I used a date in cell `E1` instead of `TODAY()` for testing purposes.

Comment: Now , Both Formulas works  , Many thanks "VBasic2008" for your help.